About low cgpa for German universities
Is it possible to get offer letter for a masters degree in civil Engineering in both public and private universities with a CGPA of 2.73 out of 4? I am open yo learn german. I am willing to go to German taught Programs as well.

duplicate/related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/210392/can-strong-research-experience-and-recommendations-offset-low-gpa-for-masters-a/210396#210396
